# Wordpress site does not fit to iphone screen

Tags: html, css, iphone, wordpress

It resizes perfect to android but it still looks like a full page in iphone so the text is really small, I ve tried everything I found about it but no luck.

this is the viewport setting right now

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
```

thank you guys, i ll appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding 'initial-scale=1' to the viewport tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />
```

And you can read more about the viewport tag on [Apple's developer site](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/UsingtheViewport/UsingtheViewport.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006509-SW29)

Comment: ok, im tried this but still no luck.. im checking ads, thanks

Comment: It works, but you need to get rid of the JavaScript function that tries to add the meta tag back in beginning: var meta = document.createElement("meta");

It's just under the beginning <body> tag.

Comment: omg! That totally did the trick !! thank you very much mrbubbles !
I did not even know about the existence of that js

Comment: Strange! It's never a good idea to put meta tags in with JS anyway, so you've done good getting rid of it.

Comment: I really dont know where that JS came out from, or what it does.. I guess it is part of the theme I used..